# Error with Sql Parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters

```
private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        string sql = ("Insert into tbl_books values NameOfBook = @book, Author =@author, Publisher=@publisher,YearPublished=@year,Category=@category,ISBN=@isbn");
        MySqlCommand sda = new MySqlCommand(sql,conn);
        sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@book", txtbook.Text);
        sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", txtauthor.Text);
        sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisher", txtpublisher.Text);
        sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", txtyear.Text);
        sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", cmbcategory.Text);
        sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbn", txtisbn.Text);
        sda.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Item has been added");
        showlv("Select * from tbl_books", lvbooks);  
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot Add Item");
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the code? It keeps on going into the catch block.

Comment: Writing an useless catch block is not a good practice. If you really want to have a catch block at least show the exception message (IE: _catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }_ ) and tell us the message text

Comment: Its better to learn SQL than make up your own syntax/structure

Comment: im sorry, im just learning.thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is messed up. Try:

```
  try
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "Insert into tbl_books (NameOfBook,Author,Publisher,YearPublished,Category,ISBN) values (@book,@author,@publisher,@year,@category,@isbn)";
    MySqlCommand sda = new MySqlCommand(sql,conn);
    sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@book", txtbook.Text);
    sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", txtauthor.Text);
    sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisher", txtpublisher.Text);
    sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", txtyear.Text);
    sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", cmbcategory.Text);
    sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbn", txtisbn.Text);
    sda.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Item has been added");
    showlv("Select * from tbl_books", lvbooks);  
}
```

And **THANK YOU** for taking the time to learn about parameterization. In-line SQL is the ripest tool for hackers and the most embarrassing and easy-to-fix security hole there is!

**NOTE:** you may want to bring your conn into the TRY block and wrap it in a USING statement to save resources:

```
  using(SqlConnection conn = getMyConnection())
  {
     conn.Open();
     //blah
     conn.Close();
  }
```

Comment: Glad to help - we've all been there. Cheers!